# Where should the file root-context.xml for a Java Hibernate project be located

Tags: java, spring

I have a freshly installed version of eclipse: Version: 2020-09 (4.17.0)
I am trying to build and deploy a spring web application to Tomcat 7.  I'm getting the following error when I do a maven-install:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: IOException parsing XML document from class path resource [root-context.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [root-context.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

I've added root-context.xml in src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring to my build path. I don't know if I need to move it somewehre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving root-context.xml to src/main/resources directory, it will be included in the eclipse target folder and run correctly.

and add this piece on yout pom.xml if you have test add in the test path

```
<build>
....
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
    </resource>
</resources>
<testResources>
    <testResource>
        <directory>src/test/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
    </testResource>
</testResources>
....
</build>
```